# Rotating a bone with Gizmo change all 3 Euler rotation angles

Tags: interface, bones, transforms, pose-mode, gizmo

I have a bone like this:

[image]

I want to change its Y rotation only. If I simply input the value I want in the property panel, it works as expected. However, if I drag-n-drop the green circle of Gizmo, all X, Y and Z values change. Why does Gizmo work like this? And how can I change only one Euler rotation value with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the gizmo orientation to "Gimbal"

[image]

Comment: All 3 rotation values still change together.

Comment: It works for me. Maybe you're rotating it past your bone constraint?

Comment: Even when it's within my bone constraint, all 3 values still change together. However, it works as expected when I set the bone's rotation mode to `XYZ` instead of `ZXY`. I don't know why.

Comment: I found the answer in another question. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/228264/object-gizmo-setting-doesnt-take-effect-for-bones