# Object gizmo setting doesn't take effect for bones

Tags: bones, transforms, pose-mode, gizmo

When I select a bone in pose mode, no matter what my Object Gizmo setting is, the Gizmo always looks the same:

[image]

[image]

Even the "global" is not global at all:

[image]

It works as expected for objects, but for bones it's always the same. Is it a bug? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @moonboots yes, but it doesn't make sense to me. As shown in the picture, the gizmo doesn't align with global axis either. It seems to align with the bone's local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in the "T" panel you select the rotation instrument, the choice between World/local has to be performed with the upper center dropdown menu in the 3D window, while if you are using the default select instrument you can activate a gizmo with the viewport gizmo menu (that in your uploaded image) and in this latter case the choice between World/local has to be performed here (and it works!).

Comment: Thank you very much! For future reference, "Transform" tool and "Select" tool both use viewport gizmo setting, while "Rotation" tool always uses local (not respecting viewport gizmo, nor transformation orientation). And it only happens for bones, not objects. I suppose it's a bug.